# How to use/unpack all **kwargs as a condition

Tags: python

I have an arbitrary amount of `**kwargs` passed to the below function that needs to check if all of them match against a dictionary record. How can I loop/unpack these kwargs to be used as conditions as per below example:

```
def get_rows_with_kwargs(list_of_dictionaries, **kwargs):
     """returns list of dictionary records where all **kwargs match"""

    results = [record for record in list_of_dictionaries
               if record[kwarg1] = kwarg1_value and record[kwarg2] = kwarg2_value and...]

    return results
```

Comment: You want to keep dicts that contain all mapping in kwargs ? Or is same as kwargs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `all` statement and pass it the generator that test all mapping from `kwargs` to be the same in the current `record`

```
def get_rows_with_kwargs(list_of_dictionaries, **kwargs):
    return [record for record in list_of_dictionaries
                   if all(record[k] == v for k,v in kwargs.items()]
```